# SVG Font Rendering Problems while rendering Text on a Path in Chrome and Safari

Tags: browser, svg, webkit, webfonts

I try to render some text along a bezier curve path in SVG:

```
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
            <path id='menu_path' d="M 80,40 Q 200,85 245,205" stroke="none" fill="none"/>
            <text fill="white">
                <textPath xlink:href="#menu_path">News Info Presse Musik</textPath>
            </text>             
        </svg>
```

In Firefox this works fine, but in Chrome and Safari, the text looks ugly (look at "Musik"). Even when I use monospace fonts and set the text to uppercase it does not change.

Here the Screenshots:

- http://imageshack.us/a/img18/3195/svgrendering.png
- http://imageshack.us/a/img705/7334/svgrenderingwithpath.png

Does somebody have an idea on how to avoid this?

I created a jsfiddle which shows the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/v6esx/

Thank you!

Comment: Have you reported this bug to webkit/chromium?

Comment: Not yet. Hmm I tried it on a MacOSX, and it works, in Chrome and safari. The problem only exists on my Windows 7...

Comment: I can confirm that the rendering looks pretty bad on linux too. If it's just windows, you can try this to see if it makes a difference: http://www.adtrak.co.uk/blog/font-face-chrome-rendering/.

Comment: Added it to: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105017

Thank you!

Comment: Strangely the JSFiddle example works fine for me in Chrome but looks terrible in Firefox on Mac OS X.