# SVG text alignment issues with a curved textpath

Tags: text, svg, d3.js, path, geometry

I want to inquire more about the problem discussed on this issue [SVG Font Rendering Problems while rendering Text on a Path in Chrome and Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850849/svg-font-rendering-problems-while-rendering-text-on-a-path-in-chrome-and-safari)

Following the example shown on http://jsfiddle.net/v6esx/4/

```
<path id='menu_path' d="M 80,40 Q 200,85 245,205" stroke="none" fill="black"/>
    <text fill="white">
        <textPath xlink:href="#menu_path">News Info Presse Musik</textPath>
    </text>
```

On Firefox 26 (OSX) the text looks misaligned, more so if a zoom is applied. The issue is even more grave on Chrome 32 on Windows 7.

You can see some screenshots from the original question on:

http://imageshack.us/a/img18/3195/svgrendering.png

[enter link description here http://imageshack.us/a/img18/3195/svgrendering.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img18/3195/svgrendering.png)

http://imageshack.us/a/img705/7334/svgrenderingwithpath.png

[enter link description here http://imageshack.us/a/img705/7334/svgrenderingwithpath.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img705/7334/svgrenderingwithpath.png)

As a D3.js developer, this impacts the look of some visualisations that use this technique. For instance you can notice this odd effect in http://bost.ocks.org/mike/uberdata/ specially on the "Downtown" and "Marina" labels

- [Screenshot 1](https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/33375/550262/F6xJQ8kOzWlUFtF/upload.png) on windows 7 + chrome 32

[image: Screenshot 1]

- [Screenshot 2](https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/33375/550262/XDQi9fni6O3qdkc/upload.png) on windows 7 + chrome 32

[image: Screenshot 2]

I want to bump this just to ask, does anybody knows a workaround, or are we just at the mercy of how each individual browser tries its best to render a text along a path?

Comment: I guess the only way to make it work consistently would be to render the generated visualisation into PNG and serve that. Of course you would lose any interactivity.

Comment: I came across the same kinds of problems. Unfortunately, I can only report even more confusing facts: Chrome + Windows 7 on my work produces decent texts, while Chrome + Windows 7 at my home looks horrible. And, yes, I checked versions of Windows and Chrome, and they are the same at both places!

Comment: For Chrome you can follow the progress on bug http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=25541.

Answer (score 1):

To a certain degree you are dependent on the browser, but you can give the browser suggestions using the [`text-rendering`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#TextRenderingProperty) property.

From the specs:

> ## 11.7.4 The ‘text-rendering’ property
>
> The creator of SVG content might want to provide a hint to the implementation about what tradeoffs to make as it renders text. The ‘text-rendering’ property provides these hints.
>
> **auto**
>   Indicates that the user agent shall make appropriate tradeoffs to balance speed, legibility and geometric precision, but with legibility given more importance than speed and geometric precision.
>
> **optimizeSpeed**
>   Indicates that the user agent shall emphasize rendering speed over legibility and geometric precision. This option will sometimes cause the user agent to turn off text anti-aliasing.
>
> **optimizeLegibility**
>   Indicates that the user agent shall emphasize legibility over rendering speed and geometric precision. The user agent will often choose whether to apply anti-aliasing techniques, built-in font hinting or both to produce the most legible text.
>
> **geometricPrecision**
>   Indicates that the user agent shall emphasize geometric precision over legibility and rendering speed. This option will usually cause the user agent to suspend the use of hinting so that glyph outlines are drawn with comparable geometric precision to the rendering of path data.

For curved or transformed text, I think `geometricPrecision` results in the best outcomes.  See [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/v6esx/13/).

Comment: Unfortunately, even that doesn't work consistently across browsers.

Comment: Yep. "Best" doesn't always mean "good"!  Even the specs make clear that it is just a "suggestion" for the browser.  Beyond that, my advice is just to do lots of testing on different systems with different fonts.

Comment: Yeah, even using the value geometricPrecision leads to the same issues cross browsers